# С помощью JS прибавить к введенным цифрам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле

```
<input id="inp1">

<p id="bonusText">//</p>
```

```js
$("#inp1").on('change keypress keyup', function() {
  if (parseInt($("#inp1").val()) >= 100) {
    $("#bonusText").html('Вы получите <b>' + $("#inp1").val() + '</b>р. <b>' + $("#inp1").val() / 2 + '</b>р. бонусных!');
  } else {
    $("#bonusText").html('Пополнив счет от 100р вы получите 50% бонусов!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp1">

<p id="bonusText">//</p>
```

Как с помощью JS сразу же прибавить к введенным числам +50%
Что бы под полем imput сразу же было видно введенное число +50%

Comment: Ваш пример работает, что не так?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzwBRd

Comment: Работает, это я дурак class с id перепутал по этому не работало.